# Turtle and draw a tree with Transcrypt

Tags: python, transcrypt

today I want draw a tree in browser with Transcrypt.
I have code in Python which is work in Skulpt:

```
import random
import turtle

def tree(size, myTurtle):
    myTurtle.pensize(size / 20)

    if size < random.randint(1,2) * 20:
        myTurtle.color("green")
    else:
        myTurtle.color("brown")

    if size > 5:
        myTurtle.forward(size)
        myTurtle.left(25)
        tree(size - random.randint(10, 20), myTurtle)
        myTurtle.right(50)
        tree(size - random.randint(10, 20), myTurtle)
        myTurtle.left(25)
        myTurtle.penup()
        myTurtle.backward(size)
        myTurtle.pendown()

window = turtle.Screen()
window.setup(800,600)
window.bgcolor("white")

myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
myTurtle.color("brown", "blue")
myTurtle.left(90)
myTurtle.speed(0)
myTurtle.penup()
myTurtle.setpos(0, -250)
myTurtle.pendown()
```

And I want to run it in browser to get this effect:

[image]
​Don't worry about text over the tree, is in polish ;) 
I run this in Skulpt, maybe you hear about it, effect you have above.
Now I want to run this in Transcrypt and compare it to Skulpt and Brython.

As you can see here:
http://www.transcrypt.org/live/turtle_site/turtle_site.html

Transcrypt somehow can draw with turtle.

What change in this code, to work with Transcrypt?

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Spróbuję coś pokombinować i dam Ci znać (mam nadzieję że zaraz).

Comment: "Compile and run" sends code on address "http://www.transcrypt.org/compile" but it gets response "404 page not exists" (PL: coś im nie działa)

Comment: it seems you can install Transcrypt using `pip` and later read [Transcrypt doc](http://sterlicht.alwaysdata.net/transcrypt.org/docs/html/installation_use.html) how to generate HTML page which you can run in browser.

Comment: I can't run it by 'compile and run' on the website either.

Comment: FYI: 'compile and run' was broken when porting to the new Transcrypt website and has been repaired. However, the normal way to use Transcrypt is by installing it locally as furas has shown below. It is a compiler and will generate a .js in the \_\_javascript\_\_ subdirectory of your project. Examples on how to connect it to HTML are at http://www.transcrypt.org/examples. The reason that Transcrypt compiles locally rather than in the browser is to obtain lean, fast pages. – Jacques de Hooge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: you need some modification in code because some functions in `Transcrypt` have different names or don't exist. You have to add `turtle.done()` to dislay result.

**turtle_tree.py**

```
import random
import turtle

def tree(size, myTurtle):
    myTurtle.pensize(size / 20)

    if size < random.randint(1,2) * 20:
        myTurtle.color("green")
    else:
        myTurtle.color("brown")

    if size > 5:
        myTurtle.forward(size)
        myTurtle.left(25)
        tree(size - random.randint(10, 20), myTurtle)
        myTurtle.right(50)
        tree(size - random.randint(10, 20), myTurtle)
        myTurtle.left(25)
        myTurtle.up()       # penup()
        myTurtle.back(size) # backward(size)
        myTurtle.down()     # pendown()

#window = turtle.Screen()   # doesn't exists
#window.setup(800,600)      # doesn't exists
#window.bgcolor("white")    # doesn't exists

myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
myTurtle.color("brown", "blue")
myTurtle.left(90)
myTurtle.speed(0)
myTurtle.up()         # penup()
myTurtle.goto(0, 250) # setpos(0, -250)     
myTurtle.down()       # pendown()

tree(135, myTurtle)

myTurtle.done() # display
```

Install `Transcrypt` using `pip`

```
pip install transcrypt
```

Compile Python into JavaScript

```
transcrypt turtle_tree.py
```

You get folder `__javascript__` with file `turtle_tree.js` (and `turtle_tree.min.js`, `turtle_tree.mod.js` but you don't need it now)

You need HTML file which loads `turtle_tree.js` and has `<div id="__turtlegraph__">` to display result.

**turtle_tree.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Turtle Tree</title>

    <style>
        #__turtlegraph__ {
            height: 600px;
            width: 800px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="__turtlegraph__"></div>
    <script src='turtle_tree.js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Put HTML file in `__javascript__` folder and open it in browser.

---

Tested on Python 3.5.2 / Linux Mint 17.3 / Firefox 48.0 - it draws in 1 second (or less).

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am interested in which functions are missed most in the Transcrypt's Turtle module, so they can be added.

Comment: You have error with compilation to JS. transcript turtle_tree.py
should be "transcrypt"

Comment: @Monica you are right - I write `script` in `transcript` all the time :)

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge I don't know - I use Transcrypt first time. Maybe all aliases like `backward` for `back`, `penup` for `up`

Comment: Thanks, I will add those in the next release.